# Default activation function in Keras

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

Does anyone know the default activation function used in the recurrent layers in Keras? https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

It says the default activation function is linear. But what about the default recurrent activation function. Nothing is mentioned about that. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Has my answer helped you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keras `Recurrent` is an abstact class for recurrent layers. In Keras 2.0 all default activations are linear for all implemented `RNNs` (`LSTM`, `GRU` and `SimpleRNN`). In previous versions you had:

- `linear` for `SimpleRNN`,
- `tanh` for `LSTM` and `GRU`.

Comment: Seems this answer is outdated. In Keras 2.2.4 default activation for LSTM is `tanh`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2081

It mentions **tanh** here for version 2.3.0 :-)